# SSL setup from MQLight NodeJS client to IBM Websphere MQ 8,.0.0.4

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-mq

Updated the question:

Trying to setup SSL / TLS from a NodeJS MQLight client to IBM Websphere MQ 8.0.0.4 server

I have a PKCS file with the private key, certificate and CA authority. Certs are chained in the following order.

RootCA
PolicyCA
Issue01CA
Streamstest

Below are the steps I followed.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configure certs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

--create store
gsk8capicmd -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw password -stash

--import cert
gsk8capicmd -cert -import -db /home/skumar04/certs/unencrypted_streams_mq_dev.pfx -target /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR_CLAIM/ssl/key.kdb -target_pw password

--List certs
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       CN=ROOTCA
!       CN=POLICYCA
!       CN=ISSUE01CA,DC=bsc,DC=bscal,DC=com
-       "CN=streams_mq_dev,OU=IT,O=Company,L=El Dorado Hills,ST=California,C=US"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configure queue manager
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
DISPLAY QMGR SSLKEYR
 (uses default location)
/var/mqm/qmgr/QMGR_CLAIM/ssl

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configure channel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER CHANNEL(CHNL_CLAIM) CHLTYPE(AMQP) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA) CERTLABL('CN=streams_mq_dev,OU=IT,O=Company,L=El Dorado Hills,ST=California,C=US') SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
```

In NodeJS client code, I am passing the public certificate

```
mq_client_options = {
  service: mq_service,
  id: config.ibmmq.mq_clientid,
  sslTrustCertificate: 'messagequeuecert.pem',
  sslVerifyName: false
```

}

Always getting socket hangup error. Are these steps correct ? Anything missing from this configuration

Comment: Which side closes the connection and when during the handshake?  It looks like you turned on mutual authentication on the server side, but you never told mq_client_options anything about a client cert.

Comment: I tried one way SSL as well by turning off the  SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) as suggested in another forum and same result. The connection isn't going through. There are no messages on the server as well. Is there any other way this can be debugged. One suggestion I received was to enable debugging on AMQP listener ("-Djavax.net.debug=ssl" ), but don't know how to set this up. Couldn't find any guide online either.

Comment: CERTLABL should contain a certificate label not a DN. If you're trying to filter a DN, you should use SSLPEER.